# SQL Server CE - High Memory Usage - Mass Inserting of Rows

Tags: c#, sql, memory-leaks, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I have absolutely massive memory usage using this code. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong? I am adding close to 50k entries into this database (I know it is a bit large for SQL Server CE) but it shouldn't have to happen all that often. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public static void AddRow(uint id, string name, uint zone, uint map, string state,
        string type, float x, float y, float z, DataBaseType dbtype)
    {
        string db = null;
        string table = null;
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
        using (var con = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (
                var cmd =
                    new SqlCeCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO " + table + "(Id, Name, Zone, Map, State, Type, X, Y, Z, Create_Date, Update_Date) " +
                        "VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Zone, @Map, @State, @Type, @X, @Y, @Z, @Create_Date, @Update_Date)", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone", zone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Map", map);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", state);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X", x);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", y);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Z", z);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Create_Date", dateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Update_Date", dateTime);
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    BotControl.StopBot();
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
   }
```

Comment: How do you _know_ you have a memory leak?

Comment: Well the program it resides in usually is around 200-300meg.  When I run this.. it grows exponentially.  It topped out at 1.5gig of memory usage before I killed it.

Comment: Use an already open connection instead of opening 50k times

Comment: ErikEJ - I thought about that, but I want to know why it is causing the memory inflation.  I am closing and disposing, I thought it should empty the memory out.  Am I wrong in how I am approach this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void AddRow(uint id, string name, uint zone, uint map, string state, string type, float x, float y, float z, DataBaseType dbtype)
{
    string db = null;
    string table = null;

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
    using (var con = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (
            var cmd =
                new SqlCeCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO " + table + "(Id, Name, Zone, Map, State, Type, X, Y, Z, Create_Date, Update_Date) " +
                    "VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Zone, @Map, @State, @Type, @X, @Y, @Z, @Create_Date, @Update_Date)", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zone", zone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Map", map);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@X", x);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Y", y);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Z", z);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Create_Date", dateTime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Update_Date", dateTime);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                BotControl.StopBot();
            }
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO.  While your answer may solve the problem, you should take some time to explain your answer.  Adding 2 lines in a code snippet may not be seen or understand by everyone.